# BeautifulSoup: Using findAll to retrieve tags without lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python on and BeautifulSoup.  I am trying to deepen my understanding of lambda expressions by rewriting them as functions and vice versa.  Could someone help me understand how to rewrite the following lambda expression using the BeautifulSoup library for Python?

```
bsObj.findAll(lambda tag:len(tag.attrs) == 2)
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
def twoTags(tag):
   if len(tag.attrs) == 2:
      return tag.attrs

bsObj.findAll(twoTags(tag))
```

I receive an error stating that the global name 'tag' is not defined.
Thank you!

Comment: You have not defined a variable named tag at `bsObj.findAll(twoTags(tag))`

Comment: Could you please give me an example?  Thank you.

Comment: I think you just want to pass your `twoTags` function to `findAll`, like `bsObj.findAll(twoTags)`. You don't actually want to call it with an argument. Also your function needs to return a boolean.

Comment: Thank you so much JCVanHamme, it's clear what I was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass in your function to `find_all`, and your function needs to return a boolean. Taken all together, your code should look like:

```
def twoTags(tag):
   return len(tag.attrs) == 2:

bsObj.findAll(twoTags)
```

Comment: Or simply `return len(tag.attrs) == 2`

Comment: Good call. Edited to reflect that.